how to connect the output of a boost converter to a battery
I have a project where I want to connect a battery and a hydrogen fuel cell to a drone, here is the specs:
please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.
the drone will need around 80 amps on 6s batteries meaning 22.2v
the hydrogen fuel cell can provide 35A@14.4V, boosting that output to 22.2V would mean a current loss of 12.3 amps meaning a full current draw of around 22.7 amps and with an efficiency of >95% lets say 95% say the output current that can be provided from the boost converter is 21.5amps the drone needs 80 amps, so I want to connect a lipo to the boost converter in parrallel and just feed the output to the drone how can i do this safely, i thought about putting diodes on both the output of the boost and the output of the battery but that would work since they would be in an or-ing configuration, the whole idea of the project is to increase the flight duration
